# Remote Procedure Call (RPC) service has failed

Tags: windows-xp, virus, worm

My windows XP machine becomes very slow. And started to show message :

```
    This system is shutting down. Please save all 
work in progress and log off. Any unsaved 
changes will be lost. This shutdown was 
initiated by NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM. 

Time before shutdown: 00:00:XX Message: 
Windows must now restart because the 
Remote Procedure Call (RPC) service 
terminated unexpectedly .
```

After one minute system reboots. Everything looks like I have  worm `Blaster`. Except that fact that I can't find virus executables. Symantec Blaster removal tool don't find it also. I have installed ESET antivirus protection, but I have no any warnings from it. Repair thing makes more complicated that I must every minute run command `shutdown -a` to prevent computer restart and there in no possibility to stop Remote procedure Call service. This service is in `Starting` mode and no actions are enabled on it. What is the best way to solve this problem?

UPD

There are two more messages:

```
Exception EOleSysError in moduleSkype.exe at 001251c9
The rpc server is unavailable
```

and

```
Cannot install fax printer driver.

Probably you have not enough privileges.
Please reboot Windows and log on as Administrator
If error occurs again - reinstall SmarThru
```

Comment: reinstall windows would be the fastest solution.

Comment: Because of some reason I can't. It is very important system for me

Comment: then remove the internet connection, and see if it forces a shutdown.

Comment: yes, it does shutdown with removed internet connection