# No permitions for administrator, RPC terminated unexpectedly error

Tags: windows, windows-xp, virus, worm

Looks I got virus. Symptoms:
My all PC users can't copy files using  copy/paste. Copy works, but paste -not. 
My Anti-Malware tool looks damaged and doesn't starts.
All users event admins has no rights to run msconfig. Have message `"An Access Denied error was returned while attempting to change service. You may log as Administrator .."`
Can't add user to admins group, because there is no tab "Member of"
Have message regarding RPC service failure and system restart. This problem described there:
[Remote Procedure Call (RPC) service has failed](https://superuser.com/questions/721062/remote-procedure-call-rpc-service-has-failed)
No networking.

If I connect my HDD to another PC like not client and scan it with antivirus - no problems found.

What is the way to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried using ComboFix? Have you tried running your Malware tool in safe mode? MalwareBytes is a great tool for this.

Comment: I would reinstall `Windows XP` there are no tools to repair the current images.  That is one of the benefits from using a modern Windows product.